# How can i grab some Parent Class Atribute values using Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python-3.7

I'm start learning Multiple Inheritance, but i can't seem to grab some Atribute values from Parent Classes.

I have 3 Classes and one of them inherits the other two.
I can print the "preco_bilhete" Attribute, but not "nome", "apelido" and "codigo_voo" Attribute values!

I'm sorry for some of my code is in Portuguese.

```
class Pessoa():
  def __init__(self, nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade):
    self.nome = nome
    self.apelido = apelido
    self.idade = idade
    self.cartaocidadao = cc
    self.nacionalidade = nacionalidade


class Voo():
  def __init__(self, companhia, cod_voo, cod_aviao, data_partida, horario_partida, data_chegada, horario_chegada, aeroporto_partida, terminal_aeroporto_partida,
           aeroporto_chegada, terminal_aeroporto_chegada, tipo_de_bagagem):
    self.companhia_aerea = companhia
    self.codigo_aviao = cod_aviao
    self.codigo_voo = cod_voo
    seld.data_voo_partida = data_partida
    self.horario_partida = horario_partida
    seld.data_voo_chegada = data_chegada
    self.horario_chegada = horario_chegada
    self.aeroporto_partida = aeroporto_partida
    self.terminal_aeroporto_partida = terminal_aeroporto_partida
    self.aeroporto_chegada = aeroporto_chegada
    self.terminal_aeroporto_chegada = terminal_aeroporto_chegada
    self.tipo_de_bagagem = tipo_de_bagagem


class Comprar_Bilhete(Pessoa, Voo):
  def __init__(self, nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade, companhia, cod_voo, cod_aviao, data_partida, horario_partida, data_chegada, horario_chegada,
           aeroporto_partida, terminal_aeroporto_partida, aeroporto_chegada, terminal_aeroporto_chegada, tipo_de_bagagem, preco):
    self.preco_bilhete = preco


cliente1 = Comprar_Bilhete("Pedro", "Figueiredo", 49, 9876543, "Portuguesa", "Easyjet", "EJ1011", "FT4537", "27-08-2020", "23:05", "28-08-2020", "01:45",
                       "Humberto Delgado - Lisboa - PT", "Terminal 1", "Stansted - Hertfordshire - UK", "Terminal 3", "Bagagem de Porão + Mala de Mão", 275.48)

print(cliente1.preco_bilhete)

print(cliente1.nome)
print(cliente1.apelido)
print(cliente1.codigo_voo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is multiple inheritance, here, your class `Comprar_Bilhete(Pessoa, Voo)` is inheriting the 2 classes `Pessoa` and `Voo`. When one class inherits another class, it also inherits it's variables and functions (since access levels of both by default is `public` in python).

You are only able to print the value of the variable: `preco_bilhete` as it is the only one being initialised in your base class - `Comprar_Bilhete`. To be able to get a value on printing the other 3 derived variables i.e. `nome` , `apelido` and `codigo_voo`, you need to pass values to initialise them as well.

This seems to fix the error you are encountering:

```
class Comprar_Bilhete(Pessoa, Voo):
  def __init__(self, nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade, companhia, cod_voo, cod_aviao, data_partida, horario_partida, data_chegada, horario_chegada,
           aeroporto_partida, terminal_aeroporto_partida, aeroporto_chegada, terminal_aeroporto_chegada, tipo_de_bagagem, preco):
    self.preco_bilhete = preco
    self.nome = nome
    self.apelido =apelido
    self.codigo_voo = cod_voo
```

Comment: Many thanks, schezfaz. That worked like a charm. i was missing exactly what you wrote in the comment.